# COUNT CASE statement returning unwanted query results

Tags: sql, count, case, teradata

The below query is looking for a count of days by object when the event was "Regular", but the query results show "Clearance" because that object falls within the specified date range.  Is there a way to make this query only show objects that had "Regular" events in date range of 4/10/2017 through Today?  I have tried Event NOT IN C or S and moving the Event in the where clause, but get the same result.

Table 1:

```
Cal_Date    Object  Event    Time Stamp Time Stamp
4/10/2017   Soap    Regular     4/10/2017   4/10/2017
4/11/2017   Soap    Sale        4/11/2017   4/14/2017
4/12/2017   Soap    Sale        4/11/2017   4/14/2017
4/13/2017   Soap    Sale        4/11/2017   4/14/2017
4/14/2017   Soap    Sale        4/11/2017   4/14/2017
4/15/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/16/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/17/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/18/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/19/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/20/2017   Soap    Regular     4/15/2017   4/20/2017
4/10/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/11/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/12/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/13/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/14/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/15/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/16/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/17/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/18/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/19/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017
4/20/2017   Shampoo Clearance   4/10/2017   12/31/2017


SELECT
    OBJECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EVENT='Regular'AND CAL_DATE BETWEEN DATE '4/10/2017' AND CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 END) AS DAYS
FROM TABLE 1
GROUP BY
    OBJECT
```

Query Results:

```
Object  Days
Soap    7
Shampoo ?
```

Desired Results:

```
Object Days
Soap    7
```

Comment: Use HAVING statement.

Comment: I don't know teradata, but isn't it possible to simply put those conditions in WHERE clause and then count(*)? In Oracle this works fine: `Select OBJECT, count(*) From TEST_MYTABLE01 WHERE EVENT='Regular' AND CAL_DATE BETWEEN to_date('10.04.2017','dd.mm.yyyy') AND sysdate Group by OBJECT`

Comment: Your result `Shampoo ?` can't be returned by your query, it will be `Shampoo 0`instead.

Comment: The slghtly different syntax in Teradata would be (Because OBJECT is a reserved word, you have to quote it. Consider to change the column name) 

`select "OBJECT", count(*)
from Table1
where EVENT = 'Regular'
and CAL_DATE between '2017-04-10'(date) and current_date
Group by "OBJECT";`

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SELECT
     [OBJECT]
     ,REGULAR = SUM(CASE WHEN [EVENT] = 'Regular' AND CONVERT(DATE,Cal_Date) BETWEEN '2017-04-10' AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
     TABLE1
GROUP BY
     [OBJECT]
```

Comment: is the REGULAR under the OBJECT supposed to be something different?  It did not recognize that part of the query.